# CommandText property has not been initialized error in gridview

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqlcommand

I have a gridview and I want to checked line in insert but I see this error:

> CommandText property has not been initialized.

I guess my mistake about strArrays. I'm working two days about it

How can I fixed?

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new  SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteSqlServer"].ConnectionString.ToString());
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   int type = 2;
   CheckBox chkUpdate = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chkSelect");

   TextBox txtAmount = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].FindControl("txtAmount");

   if (chkUpdate != null)
   {
      if (chkUpdate.Checked)
      {
         string strID = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
         GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtLocation")).Text;
         string text = this.GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
         string[] strArrays = new string[] { "INSERT INTO [OrderCancel]
                                             ([OrderID], 
                                              [Message], 
                                              [Type],
                                              [RelationProductID],
                                              [Amount]) 
                                              VALUES(" , 
                                              Request.QueryString["o"] ,
                                              ",'" , txtWhy.Text , 
                                              "',",type.ToString(),",
                                              " , strID , "," , 
                                              txtAmount.Text , ");" };
         stringBuilder.Append(string.Concat(strArrays));

         //append update statement in stringBuilder 
         stringBuilder.Append(string.Concat(strArrays));
      }
   }
   try
   {
      try
      {
         sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
         sqlCommand.CommandText = stringBuilder.ToString();
         sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
         sqlConnection.Open();
         sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
      catch (SqlException sqlException)
      {
         throw new Exception(string.Concat("Error in Updation",
                                            sqlException.Message));
      }
   }
   finally
   {
      sqlConnection.Close();
   }
```

Comment: Use `using` instead of `finally`, and get rid of your useless `catch` block.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: How can I fixed?@SLaks

Comment: Given the error message, my bet is on `chkUpdate == null`. Why don't you start to use the debugger? This could be solved in less than 10 seconds

Comment: have you tried directly writing the insert command on *CommandText* instead of String builder ?

Comment: One of your commands doesn't even have a query.

Comment: @Greg is not strArrays a query?

Comment: @VikashSingh How can I combine queries?

Comment: @mguzel I think in your case stringbuilder is empty. try to write dummy insert query directly and check.

Comment: `SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();` That is empty.

Comment: @Greg why is it empty? the same code run in another module.

Comment: You really should using a `DataGridView`.  It's a much cleaner implementation.

Comment: @Brian if (chkUpdate.Checked) is always return false why?

Comment: You are checking to see if it is `null`.  The `.Checked Property` returns a `boolean`, not a whether it is `null` or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your code could be cleaned up, you could do the following:

```
private readonly string dbConnection = "...";
private const string query = "... Column = @Column";
```

For the sake of brevity I've added *...* which will correlate to your Connection String and your query with parameters.

```
var message = String.Empty;
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnection))
     using(var command = new SqlCommand(query, dbConnection))
     {
          connection.Open();
          command.CommandType =  CommandType.Text;
          command.Parameters.Add("@Column", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = message;
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
```

So that small snippet would be inside of a method, which would pass a model of the data in your Grid.  Then when you pass a value from your Grid, then you would build your model and pass to the method which will write to your database.

Also, when you use a `StringBuilder` you will also need to call `ToString();` to ensure that it is a `string` rather than a `StringBuilder` when your utilizing.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens if you do not set the commandText property. looking at your code it looks like your stringbuilder variable is not getting set. have you tried putting a breakpoint inside your "chkUpdate.Checked" loop? if yes, can you post the sql that gets constructed in your loop

Comment: I have checkbox and textbox ever line.I want to insert line which checked.

Comment: Usually you write question marks in comments, not in answers

Comment: i had to do that because i did not have enough reputation to add comments

Comment: Originally from Karthik:  "Why do you need a string array to construct the sql statement inside for loop?"

Comment: @Karthik if (chkUpdate.Checked) is always return false why?

Comment: @mguzel : i hope you have atleast some checkboxes checked in the grid. second thing to check is that you do not have this code written in post back. where is this function of yours called from?